# Is there a JavaScript equivalent to Python's for loops?

Tags: javascript, python, loops, for-loop, iterator

So I was dissapointed to find out that JavaScript's `for ( var in array/object)` was not equivalent to pythons `for var in list:`.

In JavaScript you are iterating over the indices themselves e.g.

```
0, 
1,
2,
...
```

where as with Python, you are iterating over the values pointed to by the indices e.g.

```
"string var at index 0", 
46, 
"string var at index 2",
["array","of","values"],
...
```

Is there a standard JavaScript equivalent to Python's looping mechanism?

## Disclaimer:

> I am aware that the for (var in object) construct is meant to be used to iterate over keys in a dictionary and not generally over indices of an array. I am asking a specific question that pertains to use cases in which I do not care about order(or very much about speed) and just don't feel like using a while loop.

Comment: There's `Array.prototype.forEach`. And you shouldn't use `for ... in` to iterate through an array in JavaScript anyway.

Comment: Why? how much slower is it? I don't care about order.

Comment: Going forward, probably [`for..of` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Comment: It's unidiomatic and it has the potential of introducing weird bugs. JavaScript is a different programming language than Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for an array the most similar is the forEach loop (of course index is optional)

```
[1,2,3,4,].forEach(function(value,index){
  console.log(value);
  console.log(index);
});
```

So you will get the following output:

```
1
0
2
1
3
2
4
3
```

Answer (score 12):

In the next version of ECMAScript (ECMAScript6 aka Harmony) will be [for-of construct](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/for-of/):

```
for (let word of ["one", "two", "three"]) {
  alert(word);
}
```

`for-of` could be used to iterate over various objects, Arrays, Maps, Sets and custom iterable objects. In that sense it's very close to Python's `for-in`.

Comment: @FrancescoE. for of could be used to iterate over various collections also introduced in ES6: Set, Maps and custom iterators!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I see MUCH difference. It's easy to access the value at a given index/key

```
var list = [1,2,3,4,5];

// or...

var list = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz'};
for (var item in list) console.log(list[item]);
```

and as mentioned, you could use forEach for arrays or objects... heres an obj:

```
var list = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz'}; 

Object.keys(list).forEach(function(key, i) {
    console.log('VALUE: \n' + JSON.stringify(list[key], null, 4));
});
```

Comment: coming from python to javascript, this makes the most sense to me. +1